# Setting element attribute with attr() and getting with data() behavior

Tags: jquery

I read this discussion [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr) about the difference in usage between $ .data and $ .attr

One of the answers said this

> Data set with attr()
>
> - accessible from $(element).attr('data-name')
> - accessible from element.getAttribute('data-name'),
> - **if the value was in the form of data-name also accessible from $(element).data(name)** and element.dataset['name'] and
>     element.dataset.name
> - visible on the element upon inspection
> - cannot be objects

I tried to set a value with attr() and then take it with both attr() and date(), but the result is different from what is written.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#sl', function() {
  var selVal = $(this).val();
  $('#txt').removeAttr('data-name');
  $('#txt').attr('data-name', selVal);
  console.log("get by attr " + $('#txt').attr('data-name'));
  console.log("get by data " + $('#txt').data('name')); // get only the first attribute you set
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sl">
      <option value="foo">foo</option>
      <option value="bar">bar</option>
    </select>

<input id="txt">
```

Can you explain to me if I'm wrong or if I understand what was written? 
 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) uses internal cache it only uses the data attribute as the default value only. On performing update operation via `.data(key, value)` then DOM is **not updated**. Also on updating `.attr(key, value)` it will not update the cache.

In short don't mix `.attr()` and `.data()`